# Observer's inside view model don't trigger

Tags: android

I have a problem that happened to me during creating internal live data observer in My view model and connecting it with data binding. Right now part of my code look's like this:
Fragment:

class SearchFragment : Fragment(), Injectable {

```
@Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
@Inject lateinit var searchViewModel: SearchViewModel

private lateinit var disposable: Disposable
private var searchView: SearchView? = null
private var adapter: SearchCityListAdapter? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding: SearchFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.search_fragment, container, false)
    binding.apply { viewModel = searchViewModel
    setLifecycleOwner(this@SearchFragment)}
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    searchViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)
    submitViewModel()
}

    private fun submitViewModel(){
    viewModel.searchCityList.observe(this, Observer {it ->
        if (adapter == null){
            it?.let { adapter = SearchCityListAdapter(it)}.also {createAdapter()}
        } else {
            it?.let { adapter!!.updateList(it) }.also { adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged() }
        }
    })
    viewModel.responseStatus.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let { it ->
            when(it.status){
            Status.SUCCESS -> progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            Status.FAILURE -> progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            Status.ERROR -> progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            Status.LOADING ->progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } }
    })
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class SearchViewModel @Inject constructor(val haloApplication: HaloApplication): ViewModel() {

val progressBarVisibility: MediatorLiveData<Boolean> = MediatorLiveData()
private val responseStatus: MutableLiveData<Response> = MutableLiveData()
val searchCityList: MutableLiveData<SearchCityList> = MutableLiveData()


fun searchCity(cityName: String){
    haloApplication.networkRepository.fetchCityList(cityName, responseStatus, searchCityList)
}

init {
    progressBarVisibility.value = false
    progressBarVisibility.addSource(responseStatus){
        it?.let { when(it.status) {
            Status.FAILURE -> progressBarVisibility.value = false
            Status.ERROR -> progressBarVisibility.value = false
            Status.SUCCESS -> progressBarVisibility.value = false
            Status.LOADING -> progressBarVisibility.value = true
        } }
    }
}
```

}

XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="com.mbojec.halo.viewmodel.SearchViewModel"/>
    </data>

<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.SearchFragment">

    <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.progressBarVisibility, default=invisible}"/>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/searchCityListRecycleView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

DataBinder file:

```
import android.view.View
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter

@BindingAdapter("android:visibility")
fun setVisibility(view: View, value: Boolean) {
    view.visibility = if (value) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
}
```

For some unknown reason's the Fragment part works fine but the viewmodel part never triggers when there are changes in the responseStatus and the connection via data binding is useless. This isn't my first time with creating mediator's in view model or tranformation's but it's the first time I have such problem. I tried dozen of scenario's and each time the result is the same. First I ws blaming the new AndroidX library but their Sunflower Sample from github works also fine so I have no clue on this moment.

Answer (score 0):

`MediatorLiveData` only starts observing sources added via `addSource` when it has something observing the `MediatorLiveData` itself. Since nothing is observing `progressBarVisibility`, you won't get any callbacks.

Comment: Ok, I get it, but here's the thing, that logic i copied from my other project where I use the same pattern and in the end progreesBarVisibility is observed via databinding. I also tried to connect it in this case in the first place but nothing happened. After Your post I tried it again and still nothing. The only difference between those 2 projects are the fact that in the old one I'm using support library instead of the new AndroidX but I can't believe that this is the issue.

Comment: You haven't included any DataBinding code in your question, so I can't comment on the correctness of that code. I'd make sure you've called `setLifecycleOwner` on your binding class

Comment: Good point, I've edited me question and included the DataBinding part. And as You can see I've called 'setLifecyclerOwner' in it but still no progress in triggering that progressBarVisibility.

Answer (score 0):

You have to observe the progressBarVisibility to receive onChanged callbacks. (Every observable needs an observe to work with)

Let`s make some changes:

1. Your `progressBarVisibility` does not need to be a MediatorLiveData;
2. You dont need to make the `responseStatus`public and observe it;
3. Let your `progressBarVisibility` add `responseStatus` as source.

```
internal val progressBarVisibility: LiveData<Boolean> = Transformations.map(responseStatus) {
        when (it.status) {
            Status.LOADING -> true
            Status.ERROR, Status.SUCCESS, Status.FAILURE -> false
        }
    }
```

Now, you can observe the `progressBarVisibility`and receive callbacks.